# Wpf Application Startup appears to run twice

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a multi project WPF application, the startup project has now more than this as it's XAML;

```
<Application x:Class="Application"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Startup="Application_Startup"  ShutdownMode="OnLastWindowClose">

</Application>
```

and in the Application_Startup I have the following;

```
Private Sub Application_Startup(sender As Object, e As StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup


    SiAuto.Si.Connections = "tcp()"
    SiAuto.Si.Enabled = True
    SiAuto.Main.LogMessage(My.Application.Info.Title & " started")

    Dim controller As New MainRibbonController(New MainRibbonService)
    controller.Start
End Sub
```

SiAuto is simply a logging operation.  When I start the application I get two entries in the log generated by the SiAuto log message line and then I end up with two MainRibbonForms.  Clearly the Application_Startup is running twice but I cannot figure out why.

Has anyone seen this sort of behaviour before and could suggest where I ought to be looking to rectify the issue.  Unfortunately WPF and XAML is still relatively new to me and I'm really not sure where I should be looking.
Option strict On across all projects, everything compiles without error, so my guess is that I've made some stupid syntax error somewhere of have failed to comprehend how WPF applications really start.

If I replace all of the application_startup code with just

```
MessageBox.show("Hi")
```

I end up with two message boxes.

Comment: Are you using Prism .. ? your probably running your application from the Bootstrap as well

Comment: No , no prism and so no bootstrap  This one really has me confused.

Comment: Why don't you put a break point and look at your call stack ..

Comment: Do you have another page/control that's also calling `Application_Startup`?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of Chris, and what breakpoints I've tried have still not yielded any clues.  I'll have money that's it's something stupidly simply, and probably staring me in the face to boot.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem: my Application.xaml is

```
<Application x:Class="Application"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Startup="Application_Startup">
<Application.Resources>

</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

The Application_Startup sub fired twice: if I tried to create a new main window and show it, when I started the application two windows were shown. If i put a simple MsgBox in the sub, the message was shown twice.

```
Private Sub Application_Startup(sender As Object, e As StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
    MsgBox("Application_Startup")
End Sub
```

The problem seemd to be the "Handles" clause. The signature of the sub have to be

```
Private Sub Application_Startup(sender As Object, e As StartupEventArgs)
```

*without* 'Handles Me.Startup'

[wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net)